# Run task defintion after stack creation

Tags: aws-cloudformation, aws-fargate

The question seems simple enough. I have a bunch task definitions and a cluster in my CloudFormation template. When setting up manually I would create a task based on any definition and provide it with a CRON definition. It would then start to run.

I can't seem to find this option in CF? I found service but this only works for tasks that run indefinitely, which mine are not (they run once per day for approx. 10-20 minutes).

After some research I found out about AWS::Events::Rule which people seem to only use in conjunction with Lambda which I do not. I was unable to find any example that referenced FARGATE tasks so I'm not sure it's even possible.

If anyone has any examples of running tasks in CRON using CF, that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that [ECS scheduled tasks (cron)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/scheduled_tasks.html) would suit you:

> Amazon ECS supports the ability to **schedule tasks** on either a **cron-like** schedule or in a response to CloudWatch Events. This is supported for Amazon ECS tasks using both the **Fargate** and EC2 launch types.

This is based on CloudWatch Events which can be used to schedule many things, not only lambda.

To setup it using CloudFormation you can use [AWS::Events::Rule](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-events-rule.html) with the target of [AWS::Events::Rule EcsParameters](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-events-rule-ecsparameters.html)

Comment: Thnx marcin. I currently use the ECS scheduled tasks as you mentioned when setting up manually. I was looking for the CF equivalent of this. As mentioned in my question I already found the Rule section. Hadn't figured out the escparamaters yet so I will definetily try that first. Do you perhaps also have an example?

Comment: After some puzzling I found for the schedulers that the ECSparameters work just fine.